# How to import product images from CSV?

Tags: import

How do you import product images from a CSV file using System > Import/Export > Import?

I've followed suggestions from various sources but nothing works.  This is the format of the CSV file:

```
"sku","image","small_image","thumbnail"
90048,"test.jpg","test.jpg","test.jpg"
```

The file 'test.jpg' exists in the media/import folder so i'm not sure why this does not work.

We are using Magento CE 1.7.0.2.

When I run the import with the CSV file above the image does not get added to the product.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have set up a documentation of the product import format of Mage_ImportExport at http://www.integer-net.de/download/ImportExport_EN.pdf which describes in detail how to import for example images.

Regarding your problem: you need a few extra columns to add the image to the media gallery, otherwise it won't get imported:

```
"sku","image","small_image","thumbnail","_media_image","_media_attribute_id","_media_is_disabled","_media_position","_media_lable"
90048,"test.jpg","test.jpg","test.jpg","test.jpg",77,1,1,"Image 1"
```

Notes:

- The `_media_attribute_id` column requires the ID of the product attribute `media_gallery`. It can be obtained either from the admin panel or your custom modules using the expression `Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->getResource()->getAttribute('media_gallery')->getAttributeId();`
- The typing error `_media_lable` is intentional and hard-wired into Magento.

Comment: This also has the same result unfortunately - it doesn't import the image. The importer says the row is valid and processes it, but the image is not added to the product.

Comment: Have you checked if the _media_attribute_id is correct? I am sure that the above is working, I used it many times.

Comment: Image Import doesn't work in Magento 1.5.x, it was first implemented in 1.6.0.0.

Comment: Checked and confirmed our _media_attribute_id was 88 - updated the CSV and it works now! So for the avoidance of doubt, this CSV worked for us:


`"sku","image","small_image","thumbnail","_media_image","_media_attribute_id","_media_is_disabled","_media_position","_media_lable"
90048,"test.jpg","test.jpg","test.jpg","test.jpg",88,1,1,"Image 1"`

Comment: @AndreasvonStudnitz how to import images in Magento 1.5.X ?

Comment: @Punit-CertifiedMagentoDevPlus It's not possible. Images were added to Mage_ImportExport in 1.6. You can use DataFlow, but I wound't recommend it. You can try uRapidFlow or Magmi, but I cannot guarantee they are (still) compatible to 1.5.

Comment: @AndreasvonStudnitz ok, Thanks. Can we Import images through dataflow? in M1.5

Answer (score 0):

Add a slash before the image name.

```
"sku","image","small_image","thumbnail"
90048,"/test.jpg","/test.jpg","/test.jpg"
```

Comment: Tried that but same result - image doesn't get imported.

Comment: @Chris : Does solve your error

Comment: Bulk image import not working,   my excel format  http://i.imgur.com/E9Qbjww.png

Comment: My error : http://i.imgur.com/nSlvTX6.png

Comment: Does product with SKU 91001100 exist in the system? The error suggests not. Also check your media_attribute_id is 88 (see comments above).