# Base Image, Small Image, Thumbnail Image radio buttons are not selected after product images CSV import

Tags: admin, import, csv, product-images

I have successfully imported product images using CSV file, but Base Image, Small Image and Thumbnail Image columns in Images tab, are not selected. No Image is selected by default. So product images are not displaying in front end.

I have set `_media_is_disabled` to `0` and `_media_attribute_id` to `88`.

I have also filled `image`, `small_image`, `thumbnail`, `_media_image` with the URL's of the images. Images are shown in backend, but the base image, small image, and thumbnail are not selected.

Can someone please help? How can I get those selected after the product images CSV file is imported?

Yes exact same as that post, but i tried all things on that post, it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

you can use database query

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_media_gallery AS mg,
       catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value AS mgv,
       catalog_product_entity_varchar AS ev
SET ev.value = mg.value
WHERE  mg.value_id = mgv.value_id
AND mg.entity_id = ev.entity_id
AND ev.attribute_id IN (106,493, 109)
AND mgv.position = 1;
```

106,493, 109: image,thumb,small  --- this numbers are the attribute IDs

Comment: I want to solve and know it for the feature how i directly can select a base image, small and thumbnail with the CSV import. It must be possible..

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/18981/how-to-import-product-images-from-csv

Comment: No, not worked... Do you have a idea where in backend i can see media attribute id?

Comment: the only attribute on the backend is Media Gallerym which is not relative, if you looking for image,thumb,small you need to look at eav_attribute table using PHPMyAdmin or any other alternative