# How can i upload bulk images in magento

Tags: csv, upload

How can i upload bulk images with magento using import tool or Dataflow.

Answer (score 0):

Soory I am not able to comment so answering , you will find bulk product image upload details here as i tested it works fine for me on Magento 1.9.

[Adding images with CSV import](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9292/adding-images-with-csv-import)

Comment: where i can placed my images in magento root folder

Comment: Buddy i did this already but not working, can you send demo xl file, how you import.

Comment: You can put your all images need to be imported here : your magento root/media/import/

Comment: Can you sent demo xl file, how you import.

Comment: Export csv file of your existing  products(Using System>Import/Export>Export) and edit details(sku,name etc)  , for images put them in media/import and in csv column of image,small_image,thumbnail,_media_image
enter /imagename.jpg(ext)

Comment: I think _media_attribute_id is not entered in your case , but detailed description for image upload is here i hope this will solve your issue :
 http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/18981/how-to-import-product-images-from-csv

Comment: after entered _media_attribute_id i got error,  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Timeout sur l'obtention du verrou, query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity` (`updated_at`,`entity_id`) VALUES (?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `updated_at` = VALUES(`updated_at`)

Comment: As per my knowledge system>import/export>import is good as it provide all normal requirements need in magento , dataflows are custom import facility provided by magento to achive your custom requirements , i think in your case system>import/export>import should work fine as i used that but don't know about errors you are getting ..

Comment: I just export product as you told, and add image both media/import and xl (image name).

Comment: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Timeout sur l'obtention du verrou, query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity` (`updated_at`,`entity_id`) VALUES (?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `updated_at` = VALUES(`updated_at`)

Comment: I had used same steps like chnaged sku,name,image(image,small_image,thumbnail,_media_image) as attribute id and other details of product is already there in excel exported from magento . Did you tried this :http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/18981/how-to-import-product-images-from-csv

Comment: Buddy its working, thank you for your time with me.

Comment: anytime buddy ..